# Is it possible to access hardware register through inline assembly

Tags: c, assembly, inline-assembly

I am trying to access hardware register on a Broadcom ARM processsor through inline assemble. I have accessed hardware regiters through bare metal programming, but now I am trying to incorporate those bare metal programming codes in the C file using asm. Here is my code which toggles GPIO 17 on a Raspberry Pi 2:

```
void main() {

    __asm__(

        ".section .init\n\t"

        ".globl _start\n\t"
        "_start:"
        "ldr r0,=0x3F200000\n\t"
        "mov r1, #1\n\t"
        "lsl r1, #21\n\t"
        "str r1, [r0, #4]\n\t"
        "loop$:\n\t"

        "mov r1, #1\n\t"
        "lsl r1, #17\n\t"
        "str r1, [r0, #28]\n\t"



        "mov r1, #1\n\t"
        "lsl r1, #17\n\t"
        "str r1, [r0, #40]\n\t"

        "b loop$\n\t"

    );
}
```

but when I compile it by gcc file.c

it throws following error

```
/tmp/ccrfp9mv.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccrfp9mv.s: Error: .size expression for main does not evaluate to a constant
```

Comment: start by removing first 3 lines of your asm code as it is was c compiler/linker does.

Comment: Btw: you should be able to translate your code to c

Comment: It seems as if you are trying to duplicate names that are likely already used by the start up code. Why must you write the code in assembler in the first place?

Comment: Why was this question about developing software for the Raspberry Pi migrated from "our site for users and developers of hardware and software for Raspberry Pi"?

Answer (score 4):

You get `Error: .size expression for main does not evaluate to a constant` because you change sections inside a function.  As you can see on the [godbolt compiler explorer](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:armhfg482,options:'-xc+-std%3Dgnu11+-O3+-Wall+-fverbose-asm',sourcez:MQSwdgxgNgrgJgUwAQB4DOAXO4MDoAWAfAFDEBuA9lAIYYhTIw4DMATAPoZIBUEFYmJAHEACgEkA8gEYA7EgC8SABRMwGNp24BKAAwAPZgDFWO06YDcSJAHprSanDgAnBGjRIQ7vgIwAaJN4YCGru1C5gAOR4pLZIALbU4EpaSC4YME4C9mAeav5o9FAAnrjkFCBw8YlgyUgA3qRWVuzs1GhxLUqNTT0ARLhoCBB0/Ei44CAYADpgUxi93T1W/QDmUBQARlBI7Jhh07PzxEtNvbsY%2BwBcCyfLUM6pOr7y%2BkYmZjozcze3vXEUZFSUn8wCkXyOtyQvSgaG2TmBSGArDBhx%2BJ16mCcQP8AG0nE9EQAWAC64LRS2hFAoAAcACSXMmLCn/QHwkEo77HX4wuEI0EyRmQjEYLFspB4glIgAcpNRpCZfRZ2MRHIh3Nhyv5gt%2BmOVEpBhJ0ss5XPRGyQ6xptMZpqQWnMxAAvksgA)),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,intel:!t,labels:!t),version:3), the compiler will emits asm directives to calculate ELF metadata, with lines like:

```
.size   main,   .-main       # size_of_main  =  current_pos - start_of_main
```

Since you switch sections inside the body of `main`, the distance between `main` and the end of `main` isn't known until link time, and it's not possible to get the linker to fill in this piece of metadata that late.  (`.size` has to be an assemble-time constant, not just a link-time constant).

---

Like people commented, you should do the whole thing in C, e.g. with a global like

```
#include <stdint.h>
volatile uint32_t *const GPIO17 = (uint32_t*)0x3F200000;  // address is const, contents aren't.
```

Presumably you need to ask the OS for access to that MMIO register.  Part of the OS's job is to stop programs from talking directly to the hardware and messing up other programs that are doing the same thing at the same time.

---

Even if your code assembled, it won't link because your definition of `_start` will conflict with the one provided by the libc runtime code.

Don't try to define a function in inline asm inside another function.  Write a stand-alone function if you want to do that.